# Computing expected value $P_x(x)=c\frac{1 } {x^2} $ for $-\infty<x<\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation, random-variables, expected-value

Given:

$P_x(x)=c\frac{1 } {x^2} $ for $-\infty<x<\infty$.

$c$ is constant.

Need to compute the expected value $E(x)$.

So I know that the sum is not converge absolutely, does it means also the expected value $E(x)$ divergent?

Comment: The purported pdf is not integrable at 0, so that's not going to work (it is not a valid pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems start before you get to the expected value. This density is not normalized (and not normalizable), so it’s not the density of a random variable whose expectation you could try to compute.

Comment: Without include zero it can help?

Comment: @Deb.U: What exactly do you mean by that? Excluding the single value $0$ won't help, since the integral to $0$ diverges.

Comment: because we've learned only  discrete random variable. So maybe without zero it will help.

Comment: @Deb.U: It's not a question of what you've learned about. As it's written, one would usually assume that $x$ ranges of the real numbers. If you want to restrict it to non-zero integers, you should write that. If you do that, the probability distribution becomes normalizable, but the expected value is still undefined; see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Countably_infinite_case).

Comment: thank you for your answer and comments. That was the original question as I wrote it. , I just thought about the discrete issue after your answer. I'll try to understand why it's divergent In case of non zero integers. Didn't understand it full from Wikipedia but thank you again

Comment: @Deb.U: If you limit $x$ to non-zero integers, you get positive and negative components

$$
E^\pm[x]=\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{cx}{x^2}=\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac cx\;,
$$

and these are both infinite (since the harmonic series diverges). As explained in the Wikipedia article, if the positive and negative components both diverge, the expectation is undefined.

Comment: got it, thank you.